# Cloud Server Port says connection refused?

Tags: linux, centos5, port

I'm playing around with using a Rackspace Cloud Server (running CentosOS 5.5) as a server for the Beanstalk Message Queue system. I'm starting Beanstalk with the command line of "Beanstalkd -d -l ip address -p 11300.

All appears to start ok and no errors occur. Now I'm told I can telnet to the 11300 port on that IP address and check that all is running ok. But when I do telnet ip address 11300, I get a 'Connection refused' error, suggesting that the port is blocked or at the very least, not open.

Does anyone know if I have to open the port on a Rackspace Cloud server and if so, how I do that? Or is there something I'm missing? I'm far more into software programming than servers, so any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CentOS by default has the iptables firewall running. You will most likely have to open port 11300 try

```
/sbin/iptables -I  RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp  --dport 11300 -j ACCEPT
```

If that works then save the new firewall state with

```
/sbin/service iptables save
```

Comment: Thanks Iain,Thats sorted it!  Knew it would be my lack of server knowledge!